# Can not print Chinese characters normally in vim

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe

```
userid     movie
  1        hh泰坦尼克号
  2        Hungary Game 饥饿游戏
```

The name of movie contains Chinese

The type of `userID` is `int64`，the type of `movie` is `str`.

I use the method `pd.Series(df.movie.values,index=df.userid).to_dict()`
to convert the `dataframe` to a `dict`. Then I print the `dict`, the Chinese character display like this `\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x80\x9f\xe4\xba\x9a\xe4\xb8\xa4\xe5\x8e\xa2\xe6\xac\xa7\xe5\xae\x9d`. I use `utf-8` in the file and the Chinese characters displayed normally in the `dataframe`.
Help pls

Comment: How come, in my interpreter it prints it with the Chinese characters not with those Unicode stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can import JSON module and then:

`print json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii = False, encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: You can refer to this post: [print lists containing Chinese in python2](https://www.cnblogs.com/niansi/p/8018810.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't any relationship between this problem and `json` or `pandas` or `dataframe` or `vim` or anything else.

It is just a problem about displaying characters which are not encoded with `ascii`.

And it will only happen when you are using Python2 but not Python3.

You can confirm it in Python2:

```
a = {1: "泰坦尼克号"}
print a
# {1: '\xe6\xb3\xb0\xe5\x9d\xa6\xe5\xb0\xbc\xe5\x85\x8b\xe5\x8f\xb7'}
```

But you can still print it normally by:

```
print a[1]
# 泰坦尼克号
```

So the problem is how does `dict` handle `__str__` or `__repr__` in Python2.

The solution using `json` is to convert the whole `dict` into `str` with `utf-8` encoding, so it works.

---

BTW, the **best** solution is to use Python3.

Comment: Do you really need to print it? Focus what you actually need. I have said this is just a problem about display but there is nothing wrong with your data stored in `dict`. If you really need to print, just use `json`.

Comment: ok, I should focus on what I need. But I just want to know the reason. Thank you